# Array of ObjectIds in Mongoose 3.8

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema called Message and it has a property `replies` which are also Message objects. I am trying to define it in mongoose, but `replies` keeps returning undefined.

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    replies: [{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Message'}],
    roomId: String,
    sendTime: Date,
    content: String,
    parentId: Schema.ObjectId
});
```

I've also tried  `replies: [MessageSchema]` and `replies:[Schema.ObjectId]` but all of them keep returning undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "all keep returning"? Are you trying to create new items or do you have an existing collection that you are trying to use this with? In either case you either have an array of `ObjectID` values or an array containing actual objects depending on whether you are intending  to reference or embed the data.

Comment: Sorry, "all keep returning" meant all my different attempts returned `undefined`. I'm trying to reference the data, so I want `replies` to store just ObjectIds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code you are listing so it's what you are not showing us that causes the problems.

When you reference you are going to both save a copy of the object in the collection and also add that related ObjectId value to the array of objects that are in "reply" in your case.

There are several ways to do it, but a good safe MongoDB way is using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to add additional items.

As a complete example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var userSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String
});

var messageSchema = new Schema({
  "sender": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "User" },
  "replies": [{ "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Message" }],
  "roomId": String,
  "sendTime": { "type": Date, "default": Date.now },
  "content": String,
  "parentId": Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

var Message = mongoose.model( "Message", messageSchema );
var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

async.waterfall(
  [
    // Clean up samples
    function(callback) {
      async.each(
        [User,Message],
        function(model,callback) {
          model.remove({},callback);
        },
        callback
      )
    },

    // Create user
    function(callback) {
      User.create({ "name": "Bill" },callback);
    },

    // Create a message
    function(user,callback) {
      Message.create({
        "sender": user._id,
        "roomId": "1",
        "content": "message"
      },function(err,message) {
        callback(err,user,message);
      });
    },

    // Create a reply
    function(user,message,callback) {
      Message.create({
        "sender": user._id,
        "roomId": "1",
        "content": "reply",
        "parentId": message._id
      },callback);
    },

    // Save that reply on the parent
    function(message,callback) {
      Message.findByIdAndUpdate(
        message.parentId,
        { "$push": { "replies": message._id } },
        function(err,message) {
          console.info( message );
          callback(err);
        }
      );
    },

    // List that
    function(callback) {
      Message.find({},function(err,messages) {
        if (err) callback(err);

        console.log(
          "All:\n%s",
          JSON.stringify( messages, undefined, 4 )
        );
        callback();
      });
    }

  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And the output:

```
{ _id: 54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef67,
  sender: 54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef66,
  roomId: '1',
  content: 'message',
  __v: 0,
  sendTime: Mon Mar 02 2015 14:58:41 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
  replies: [ 54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef68 ] }
All:
[
    {
        "_id": "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef67",
        "sender": "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef66",
        "roomId": "1",
        "content": "message",
        "__v": 0,
        "sendTime": "2015-03-02T03:58:41.387Z",
        "replies": [
            "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef68"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef68",
        "sender": "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef66",
        "roomId": "1",
        "content": "reply",
        "parentId": "54f3dff198a8c85306a2ef67",
        "__v": 0,
        "sendTime": "2015-03-02T03:58:41.393Z",
        "replies": []
    }
]
```

That way if you called `.populate()` on an message that has "replies" present, it will go back to the collection and retrieve the related data and make it appear that data was part of that item as well.

Please not that such magic does not happen "recursively" without your own intervention. It's just a basic helper, so if you want more then you still have to do the lifting yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to try it out. Is `async.waterfall` necessary?

Comment: @Carpetfizz No it's just a demonstration and a simple way to pass through values without nesting code blocks.