# Mongoose Store Array of ObjectId

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 models that I am working on. A user can have many movies that he likes and a movie can be liked by more than one user. I have decided to store these information in each user.

I am trying to store the movieid in the array moviesLiked but each time I save, it throws an error, **CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value '1234' at path 'moviesLiked'**.

I did try to retrieve the movie object and push the movie.id into the array but it didn't seem to work for me and have since removed it. I might have been doing it wrong and would be nice if someone told me which direction I should be heading in as I am very new to Mongoose.

Resource based on
[Array of ObjectIds in Mongoose 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802125/array-of-objectids-in-mongoose-3-8)

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    moviesLiked: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

movie.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MovieSchema= new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
```

And finally in my routes/index.js

```
router.route('/api/users/:userid/:movieid').put(function(req, res) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.userid, 
        { '$push': { 'moviesLiked': req.params.movieid } },
        function(err, user) {
            console.log( user );
        }
    );
});
```

Update: pulled the id instead. Not working though.

```
router.route('/api/users/:userid/:movieid').put(function(req, res) {
    Movie.findById(req.params.movieid, function(err, movies) { 
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.userid, 
            { '$push': { 'moviesLiked': movies.id } },
            function(err, user) {
                console.log( user );
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you passing your movie id from your schema as a route param or the mongodb _id?

Comment: It is passed as a route param. I have tried retrieving findById() the movieId and passing the mongo _id before as well with movie.id but still the same result.

Comment: Pass the default MongoDB _id as your route parameter rather than the id field that you have defined in your schema

Comment: I tried it and updated my code. It still doesn't work. Did I pull the id incorrectly by any chance?

Comment: I meant pass _id to your route '/api/users/:userid/:movieid' ...so the movieid param would be _id of whichever movie you want to save

Comment: _id is 1234. I did not use the _id instead I overwrote it with my own id. But I will try and create a new entry with _id and test it.

Comment: Your own id is of type Number but your moviesLiked array expects type ObjectId

Comment: I get it now. It does work if I stop using my own Id. Not really the way I hoped to do it though. Is there a way to use my id instead?

Comment: I've added an answer with a possible way to use your own id instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your own id is of type Number but your moviesLiked array expects type ObjectId.

Your moviesLiked array should contain a list of ids corresponding to the default _id field from your Movie model.

I believe refs can only reference _id but if you want to use your own id then you could try setting _id to your own id in your MovieSchema and then set your moviesLiked type to match in your UserSchema:

*user.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    moviesLiked: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Movie' }]
});
```

*movie.js*

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MovieSchema= new Schema({
    _id: { type: Number, unique: true },
    name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
```